# Conditional form of uncertainty relation for Fourier conjugate variables

Tags: fourier-analysis, quantum-mechanics

This question comes from and is on the border of physics, but I ask it here to seek possible connection to a more general mathematical framework and/of references to existing literature.

For a given complex valued $\psi(\omega)$, let us define two quantities:

1. Fourier transform: $\tilde{\psi}(t)\equiv \int \psi(\omega) \, e^{- i \omega t} d \omega$
2. Second moment of the complementary variable: $\Delta t^2 \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} | \tilde{\psi}(t)|^2  t^2 \, dt - \left( 
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} | \tilde{\psi}(t)|^2  t \, dt \right)^2$

I believe I can prove the following theorem:

For a given non-negative real-valued function $p(\omega)$, among all complex-valued functions $\psi(\omega)$ such that $|\psi(\omega)| =p(\omega)$, the minimal value of $\Delta t$ is attained for $\psi(\omega)=p(\omega) e^{- i \omega t_0}$ with an arbitrary constant $t_0$.

**Question**: what is the correct name and a reference for the above theorem?